# GridView Column validation, display error message don't loose focus

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress

I need to validate a gridView column such as the sum of all elements in the column are <=100;

If the user enters a value and the sum exceeds the limit i want to display a custom error message.

I've tried using this event on the column's repositoryedit:

```
 void pinEditRepositoryItem_Validating(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        gridview1.SetColumnError(m_imixGridView.Columns["MyColumn"], "ColumnSum must be <= 100", DevExpress.XtraEditors.DXErrorProvider.ErrorType.Critical);
    }
```

However, when setting

```
              e.Cancel = true;
```

I get the default message "Invalid Value".

If i use

```
       gridview1.SetColumnError(m_imixGridView.Columns["MyColumn"], "ColumnSum must be <= 100", DevExpress.XtraEditors.DXErrorProvider.ErrorType.Critical);
```

only, the error message is correct but if i click outside the focus is lost.

I've seen that there are multiple methods for validating rows but didn't find a solution that will suit best in this case.

Is it possible to disable 'unfocus' on a cell if the validation fails?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Source](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q384408.aspx)

> I am afraid it is difficult to determine the cause of the issue based
>   on the provided information. Generally, the `ValidatingEditor` event
>   fires when an *active editor is closed*, and its *value is changed*.
>   The `ValidateRow` event fires when a `current row loses focus`, and
>   some of its values has been changed.

I suggest you to go through following links:
[Validating Rows](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument749)
[Validating Editors](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument748)
[BaseView.ValidatingEditor Event](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseBaseView_ValidatingEditortopic)

Check this example:

```
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid;
using DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls;

private void gridView1_ValidatingEditor(object sender, BaseContainerValidateEditorEventArgs e) {
    GridView view = sender as GridView;
    if(view.FocusedColumn.FieldName == "Discount") {
        //Get the currently edited value 
        double discount = Convert.ToDouble(e.Value);
        //Specify validation criteria 
        if(discount < 0) {
            e.Valid = false;
            e.ErrorText = "Enter a positive value";
        }
        if(discount > 0.2) {
            e.Valid = false;
            e.ErrorText = "Reduce the amount (20% is maximum)";
        }
    }
}

private void gridView1_InvalidValueException(object sender, InvalidValueExceptionEventArgs e) {
    //Do not perform any default action 
    e.ExceptionMode = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ExceptionMode.NoAction;
    //Show the message with the error text specified 
    MessageBox.Show(e.ErrorText);
}
```

**Editor validation** takes place when attempting to save the edit value (using the `PostEditor` method) or when closing the active editor. First, the automatic validation is performed. The editor determines whether it can accept the entered value. After the automatic validation has been performed, the `ValidatingEditor` event is raised. Handle this event to implement custom constraints on cell values.

If your condition fails then set the `e.Valid = false;` and the `e.ErrorText = "ColumnSum must be <= 100";` and also handle the `InvalidValueException` event of gridview.